# Need to extend url length on IIS express and I am getting a 400 BadRequest

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, visual-studio-2019, iis-express

I am trying to make a Get request against an API and the URL contains a lot of Guids.
How can set an unlimited URL limit to my IIS express in order to make this query.

Query example:

```
https://localhost:44329/api/user_collections/(7e9046ff-93ba-4f4f-a185-0330967e33b4,e88605f2-772f-493a-b9ee-1b561f45af57,e8796bef-cf53-47ca-85e7-1c683775c40f,2f795791-dfd7-469d-881b-217ad3aeb4f0,2f795791-dfd7-469d-881b-217ad3aeb4f0,e36c1106-e38d-40aa-816c-318e06bc9443,e36c1106-e38d-40aa-816c-318e06bc9443,dd07a986-a63a-4a8c-8f77-3944955ab5d4,46299c82-cbf8-4256-996b-4ac6ef975f09,46299c82-cbf8-4256-996b-4ac6ef975f09)
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/httpsys-registry-windows#registry-keys Things like UrlSegmentMaxCount.

Comment: @LexLi changing the registry is pretty invasive, don't you think?

Comment: Certain settings can only be changed via registry keys, whether you like it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out [there’s a registry settin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/httpsys-registry-windows#registry-keys)g for indicating the maximum length of any individual path segment called “UrlMaxSegmentLength.” The default value is 260 characters. When our route value was longer than that, we’d get the 400 error.

The solution is to **pass the value on the querystring rather than as a route value**. Something to consider if you have route values that are going to be long. Of course, this isn’t a problem with routing, just that you can get into the situation pretty easily when you get into the habit of pushing parameters into the route. It might be nice in future versions of routing to have some sort of max length check when generating full route URLs so you can’t generate a path segment greater than, say, 256 characters without getting an exception.